# Proper way of disposing of a buffer with GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW data

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

When creating a object I do

```
glGenBuffers(1, &m_buf); checkError();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_buf); checkError();
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices_length, vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW); checkError();
```

to create and initialize a buffer. I use `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` because the geometry will be modified.

When I need to modify the geometry of an object I call `glBufferData` with the new data. I know it's not the most efficient way, but I'm not concerned with efficiency at the moment.

When I no longer need said object I do

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); checkError();
glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_buf); checkError();
```

to delete the allocated buffer.

After `glDeleteBuffers` of a buffer with `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` data, any call to `glDrawArrays` for different objects generates `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. When the deleted buffer has `GL_STATIC_DRAW` data there are no problems. After the error the screen appears completely black.

I call `glGetError()` after every OpenGL call in `checkError()`. The first error reported is after `glDrawArrays` for a different object.

```
11-20 18:46:42.199: E/Adreno200-ES20(3023): <gl_draw_error_checks:418>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
11-20 18:46:42.209: D/graphics(3023): glError: 1282
```

Using OpenGL ES 2.0. Testing on HTC One J (HTC J ISW13HT), Android version 4.0.4.

What is the proper way of disposing of a buffer with GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW data?

Comment: there is probably still a buffer bound to one of the attributes

Comment: You're right! After adding `glDisableVertexAttribArray` of the appropriate attributes the problem is solved. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably still a buffer bound to one of the attributes.

Go through the attributes that it was bound to and call `glDisableVertexAttribArray` for it (or bind another buffer to it).